# No prompt showing for WKWebView getUserMedia({audio: true})

Tags: javascript, macos, audio, webkit, getusermedia

A JavaScript library implementation (Twilio Voice JS) on MacOS requires media permissions, specifically microphone permissions.

To do so in web browsers, one typical calls:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
    .then((e) => alert("Permissions granted"))
    .catch((e) => alert("Permissions Denied"))
```

The same could be done in a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) either by [evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) or by loading a [script (or html file) from local resources](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/wkwebview-load-html-file-from-app-bundle/). *In these cases `navigator.mediaDevices` would only be made available if called from a "secure" site (i.e. https) or loaded locally e.g. via an html file from bundle resources. [See secure note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices)*

**The issue is quite simple:**

Calling `getUserMedia` via [Safari WKWebView inspector console](https://webkit.org/blog/13936/enabling-the-inspection-of-web-content-in-apps/) hangs in terminal. It doesn't complete. It doesn't show a prompt. The promise doesn't resolve, reject or throw an error, nothing.

---

#### Context

- **Environment:** Flutter MacOS plugin, XCode 14.2. Targeting macOS +11.0 with a Headless WKWebView.
- `Info.plist` includes Microphone permissions as required
- Hardened Runtime includes `Audio Input`, Sandbox includes bluetooth, Audio Input & outgoing connections.
  [image]
- Manually prompting permissions [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/requesting_authorization_to_capture_and_save_media) shows prompt.
- (System) `Preferences > Security & Privacy > Microphone` lists app with permissions.
- `Safari (console) > Preferences > Websites > Microphone` does not show any allowed permissions, with `Ask` required

[image]

#### Media & supporting docs

##### Current output

Current output for `enumeratedDevices` and `getUserMedia` in `WKWebView`:

[image]

##### Expected output

Safari output, showing `enumeratedDevices` before and after requesting permissions:

[image]

The issue is quite simple: calling `getUserMedia` via [Safari WKWebView inspector console](https://webkit.org/blog/13936/enabling-the-inspection-of-web-content-in-apps/) hangs in terminal. It doesn't complete. It doesn't show a prompt. The promise doesn't resolve, reject or throw an error, nothing.

---

#### Question

What is causing this hanging/what am I missing?

#### MCVE

Github: [WKWebView](https://github.com/cybex-dev/WKWebView)

---

### UPDATE 1

I came across this SO post about [Hardened Runtime Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048995/avaudioengine-halc-shellobject-errors-no-audio-what-can-i-even-look-for) - this may be a good location to dig in to the cause.

`enumerateDevices` shows:

```
0: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: 'default', kind: 'audioinput', label: 'Default - Internal Microphone (Built-in)', groupId: '...'}
1: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: '...', kind: 'audioinput', label: 'Internal Microphone (Built-in)', groupId: '...'}
2: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: '...', kind: 'audioinput', label: 'Microsoft Teams Audio Device (Virtual)', groupId: '...'}
3: InputDeviceInfo {deviceId: '', kind: 'videoinput', label: '', groupId: ''}
4: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: 'default', kind: 'audiooutput', label: 'Default - Internal Speakers (Built-in)', groupId: '...'}
5: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: '...', kind: 'audiooutput', label: 'Internal Speakers (Built-in)', groupId: '...'}
6: MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: '...', kind: 'audiooutput', label: 'Microsoft Teams Audio Device (Virtual)', groupId: '...'}
```

**Hardened Runtime Permissions:**

- Audio Input
- Camera

Below is the output for both with and without the above permissions:

WITH

```
getDevices: nil // JS response

2023-07-25 14:32:19.758054+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070748] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000266820> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2023-07-25 14:32:19.786676+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070748]   saved enable noise cancellation setting is the same as the default (=1)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.833763+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070748] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000271760> 30010C1C-93BF-11D8-8B5B-000A95AF9C6A
2023-07-25 14:32:19.855809+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070748] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000271760> 30010C1C-93BF-11D8-8B5B-000A95AF9C6A
2023-07-25 14:32:19.862903+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALC_ShellObject::GetPropertyData: call to the proxy failed, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.862932+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALPlugIn::ObjectGetPropertyData: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.864197+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALC_ShellObject::GetPropertyData: call to the proxy failed, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.864239+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALPlugIn::ObjectGetPropertyData: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.865446+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALC_ShellObject::GetPropertyData: call to the proxy failed, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.865476+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALPlugIn::ObjectGetPropertyData: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.867520+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALC_ShellObject::GetPropertyData: call to the proxy failed, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
2023-07-25 14:32:19.867541+0200 WKWebView[60215:1070703]  HALPlugIn::ObjectGetPropertyData: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1852797029 (nope)
```

and,

WITHOUT

`navigator.mediaDevices` is undefined (as expected by Mozilla's documentation on [secure environments & mediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices)), resulting in the following output:

```
getDevices error: Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=14, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=39, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=file:///Users/mac/Library/Caches/JetBrains/AppCode2023.1/DerivedData/WKWebView-gziqxifpucvqvngtmvedcjalfcqj/Build/Products/Debug/WKWebView.app/Contents/Resources/index.html, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})
```